# Pass an event object to a function by code

Tags: javascript, function, events, backbone.js

I've looked quite a bit for an answer to my question, but haven't found anything similar yet.  Essentially, I want to call a function that accepts an event and would normally be attached to  an element via a click or some other event, but instead just call it directly.

In essence, I know that I can do this to call my function (written in jQuery):

```
function updateThisValue(event) {
    ...some code...
}

jQuery('#myElement').on('click', updateThisValue);

jQuery('#myElement').trigger('click');
```

Is there a way, instead, to call the function directly?

```
function updateThisValue(event) {
    ...some code...
}

updateThisValue(***jQuery event object here***);
```

For context, I'm using Backbone to update a form on a webpage, and have defined a custom View that is defined to call one of its methods (updateThisValue) on particular events.  Within a different method of the same View I want to be able to call the "updateThisValue" method directly.  However, "updateThisValue" uses the event object within its code.  So if I call the method directly, it fails with an error.

Is there a way to do this?  Or do I just have to trigger the thing manually (by code) as per my first I-know-I-can-do-it-this-way example?  Just feels like a hack, is all.

Thanks.

Comment: What part of the event object do you need? Maybe you can use something like `updateThisValue({target: <DOMNode>})`

Comment: What would updateThisValue do with the event object? As Javascript is a dynamic language, you could pass any object as long as it "looks" like a jQuery event object regarding the properties and functions that are accessed. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself needing to call a method directly, then that method likely shouldn't be defined in a way that directly processes an event.  I would propose refactoring your code:

```
function updateThisValue(arg0, arg1, arg2, ...) {
    ... some code ...
}

function updateThisValueUsingEvent(event) {
    // do nothing except extract the necessary values from event
    updateThisValue(event.target, event.which);
}

jQuery('#myElement').on('click', updateThisValueUsingEvent);
// direct invocation:
updateThisValue($(selector)[0], 2);
```

From an MVC perspective your updateThisValue function is part of the Controller.  The updateThisValueUsingEvent is a binding from your View into your Controller.  Especially since it sounds like it deals directly with your Model (by updating a value) you should attempt to separate the View/Controller entanglement.

You can also define `updateThisValueUsingEvent` as an inline anonymous function inside your event binding call:

```
jQuery('#myElement').on('click', function(e) {
    updateThisValue(e.target, e.which);
});
```

Comment: Ah, you're a genius.  This is exactly what I should do.  I'm kind of new to the whole MVC structure and have inherited this fairly complex, partially-entangled javascript code to update.  Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `updateThisValue` with a jQuery event object if you **HAVE** a jQuery event object.

So you can do this:

```
var updateThisValue = function(e) {
 //...
}

//The below two pieces of code are equivalent.
$('#myelement').on('click',updateThisValue);

$('#myelement').on('click',function(e) {
   updateThisValue.apply(this,[e]);
});
```

The only reason why I used `.apply()` in the second code sample and didn't just do `updateThisValue(e)` directly is in case you want to use a reference to `this` in the `updateThisValue` function (which will refer to this dom node that handled that event). If you don't need a reference to `this` in `updateThisValue` then you can just as easily do the following:

```
$('#myelement').on('click',function(e) {
   updateThisValue(e);
});
```